# Motivated or Motivating

Tags: expressions, adjectives, past-participles, present-participles

Which answer is correct?

> The renovation project has been led by a highly `_____` group of designers.
>
> - A) motivated
> - B) motivating

If not B, why not?

Comment: Both fit, and mean different things. Were the designers motivated, or did they do the motivating of others?

Comment: This is just like the difference between *nauseated* and *nauseating*.

Comment: You may also want to check out [our sister-site for English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Please add more context & explain why you have a problem here.

Comment: What research have you done into the meanings of these alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Both *motivated* and *motivating* work, but they mean different things.

The renovation project has been led by a highly *motivated* group of designers: The designers are very interested in completing their task as well as possible. They have motivation.

The renovation project has been led by a highly *motivating* group of designers: The designers encourage others to find interest in the renovation, or the other workers are inspired by the designers. The designers give motivation to others.